# Is there a Bailey–Borwein–Plouffe (BBP) formula for e?

Tags: algorithms, computational-number-theory, digits

I recently used Bailey–Borwein–Plouffe formula to implement a [π digit generator](https://www.browserling.com/tools/pi-digits). Now I also want to implement an `e` digit generator, for the [Euler number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)).

I've been searching and reading papers but it looks like there is no BBP formula for `e`. Is there one? Does anyone know if there has been recent progress on this?

Comment: Perhaps you should spell out BBP as [Bailey–Borwein–Plouffe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula).

Comment: My comments at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1817064/bbp-formula-for-e while not conclusive may have some weight.

Comment: You're using BBP to generate **decimal** digits of pi?

Comment: Unlikely that they have one for $e$ since it would be publicized quickly. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula

Answer (score 6):

I wish I had 50+ reputation so I could comment : I visited your website and I saw that you are not actually using what the BBP is famous for namely extracting the $n$-th digit in base-16. Instead you are giving *all* the digits in base 10. If that is what you want for $e$ then the power series $\sum_{k \geq 0} 1/k!$ already does the job sufficiently well.

Comment: Now I have 50+ reputation! No need to up-vote anymore.

Answer (score 1):

What you are actually looking for, is the [Spigot Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spigot_algorithm) which is also known as "droplet algorithm".
That algorithm has been described a few years ago in the german "Spektrum der Wissenschaft" and should thus also have been described in the "Scientific American".

Especially the algorithm for $e$ is known and an implementation in R can be found [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/numbers/versions/0.6-1/topics/dropletPi).